# SQL SELECT request using count(*) with multiple GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I am currently in an internship and I have to create a missing view, this preventing a website to work perfectly.

This view has to contain multiple informations, but also the number of rows with each couple status/process as in the following:

```
 +----------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
 | status         | process | project  | idprocess | idproject | number |
 +----------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
 | Not applicable | AP      | tms-data |        17 |         2 |    432 |
 | Not applicable | AP+51   | tms-data |        18 |         2 |    432 |
 | Not applicable | AR      | tms-data |        19 |         2 |    432 |
 | Realized       | AP      | tms-data |        17 |         2 |    432 |
 | Realized       | AP+51   | tms-data |        18 |         2 |    432 |
 | Realized       | AR      | tms-data |        19 |         2 |    432 |
 | Safety         | AP      | tms-data |        17 |         2 |    432 |
 | Safety         | AP+51   | tms-data |        18 |         2 |    432 |
 | Safety         | AR      | tms-data |        19 |         2 |    432 |
 | Ticket         | AP      | tms-data |        17 |         2 |    432 |
 | Ticket         | AP+51   | tms-data |        18 |         2 |    432 |
 | Ticket         | AR      | tms-data |        19 |         2 |    432 |
 | To be designed | AP      | tms-data |        17 |         2 |    432 |
 | To be designed | AP+51   | tms-data |        18 |         2 |    432 |
 | To be designed | AR      | tms-data |        19 |         2 |    432 |
 | Validated      | AP      | tms-data |        17 |         2 |    432 |
 | Validated      | AP+51   | tms-data |        18 |         2 |    432 |
 | Validated      | AR      | tms-data |        19 |         2 |    432 |
 +----------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
 18 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I'm using MySQL. I don't understand why it counts this way, any ideas ?

Here is the script I've been using so far :

```
 SELECT alstom_status.name AS status,
        alstom_process.name AS process,
        alstom_project.name AS project,
        alstom_process.idprocess AS idprocess,
        alstom_project.idproject AS idproject,
        count(*) AS number
 FROM alstom_rule INNER JOIN alstom_status ON idstatus
                  INNER JOIN alstom_project ON idproject
                  INNER JOIN alstom_process ON idprocess
 GROUP BY alstom_status.name, alstom_process.name
 ORDER BY process;
```

Comment: you need 5 group bys not 2 I believe

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` clause looks correct, but you should not select columns unless they also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, or are inside of aggregate functions like `COUNT`.

Comment: @Drew You could be right about that.

Comment: We would normally say `JOIN y ON y.some_column = x.some_columm` or `JOIN y USING(some_column)`

Comment: @Strawberry is right, in fact I usually don't precise because in my own tables, I prefer to give the same name for the same columns of different tables, but here it is not the case (idstatus is named status in the table rule)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
This works always for me !

SELECT alstom_status.name AS status,
           alstom_process.name AS process,
           alstom_project.name AS project,
           alstom_process.idprocess AS idprocess,
           alstom_project.idproject AS idproject,
           count(*) AS number
    FROM alstom_rule INNER JOIN alstom_status ON idstatus
                     INNER JOIN alstom_project ON idproject
                     INNER JOIN alstom_process ON idprocess
    GROUP BY status, process,project,idprocess, idproject;
```

You may use ( group by alstom_status.name,alstom_process.name,alstom_project.name, alstom_process.idprocess,alstom_project.idproject)